# Given a list of binary numbers (0s and 1s), determine the number of possible arrangements of distinct binary sequences using given 0s and 1s

Tags: python, string, list, binary

Given a list of binary numbers (0s and 1s), determine the number of possible arrangements of distinct binary sequences using given 0s and 1s.

Input Format:

A single line of input containing 0s and 1s

Output Format:

Print an integer value indicating the number of possible arrangements using given 0s and 1s

Example:

Input:

0 1 0 1

Output:

6

Explanation:

For the given input, the possible distinct binary sequences that can be formed are 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100.

Hence the output is 6.
I have tried this but getting error.

```
import math
c=input().split()
a=0
b=0
for i in c:
  if int(i)==0:
    b+=1
  if int(i)==1:
    a+=1
answer=int(math.factorial(len(c))/(math.factorial(a)*math.factorial(b)))
print(answer,end="")
```

[Click here to see my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxOe1.png)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen 0! is 1 so there won't be a division by 0. I agree that it's hard to tell without seeing the failing test, though. Their formula for `answer` is correct, so it has to be an edge case.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.

Comment: No, not at all. I tried with 3 zeros,4 ones,I am not getting any error.

Comment: That was my next thought. I'm relatively certain the code posted is correct. As well, what happens when you return `0` for an empty input. I'm not saying that's right(because it's not), but I have seen quite a few people try to make that argument...

Comment: No, there are no constraints for input. We can take any length. There is no maximum length to the input string.

Comment: There has to be any input in form of 0's or 1's.It is the rule of question.

Comment: Is the wording the post the exact wording you received? Because as it stands, what's in the post does indicate you can be given no numbers. An empty set is still a set.

Comment: I have posted each and every word of the question given to me. The wording of the post is exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
c=input()
c=list(c)
a=0
b=0
for i in c:
    if int(i)==0:
        a+=1
    if int(i)==1:
        b+=1
answer=int(math.factorial(len(c))/(math.factorial(a)*math.factorial(b)))
print(answer)
```

Comment: @AmazonKing Do consider accepting an answer if it works by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
n=input().split()
a=math.factorial(len(n))//(math.factorial(n.count("1"))*math.factorial(n.count("0")));
print(a,end="")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

```
def fact(n):
  if(n==0):
    return 1
  else:
    return n*fact(n-1)
  
myList = list(map(int,input().split()))
a = myList.count(0)
b = myList.count(1)
c = len(myList)
print(int(fact(c)/(fact(a)*fact(b))),end="")
```

Comment: Classical newbie mistake: you have replaced python's 'list()' object with raw input data from the user mapped to int.  Overwriting the list object with user data is likely to cause mysterious errors down the line.